# javascript compare or match two dates with same format

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datetime, date-parsing

I have facing an issue in Javascript dates. i want to compare or match two dates and show its another array.

My Code:

```
var ts_hms = new Date().toISOString().
  replace(/T/, ' ').      // replace T with a space
  replace(/\..+/, '');     // delete the dot and everything after
  console.log(ts_hms);     //format 2020-05-07 08:04:26
```

console log data (Date format)

```
Array1:
[2020-05-07 02:15:00]

Array2:
[2020-05-07 08:04:26, 2020-05-07 09:04:26, 2020-05-07 10:04:26]
```

**Expected Output**

Array3: `[same data are shows here]`

Remember: dates value are changes  (it is not fixed value)

```
Array1:
[2020-05-07 04:15:00]

Array2:
[2020-05-07 06:04:26, 2020-05-07 07:14:26, 2020-05-07 08:24:26]
```

How can i match two dates?

Anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could compare date arrays.

```js
let array1 = [new Date("2020-05-07 02:15:00")]

let array2 = [new Date("2020-05-07 08:04:26"), new Date("2020-05-07 09:04:26"), new Date("2020-05-07 10:04:26")]

let array3 = [new Date("2020-05-07 08:04:26"), new Date("2020-05-07 09:04:26"), new Date("2020-05-07 10:04:27")]

const areArraysEqual = (array1, array2) => {
  // for only date part comparison, strip time part
  array1 = [...array1.map(date => new Date(date.toDateString()))]
  array2 = [...array2.map(date => new Date(date.toDateString()))]
  

  if(array1.length !== array2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  for(let i = 0; i < array1.length ; i++) {

    if(array1[i].valueOf() !== array2[i].valueOf()) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(array1)
console.log(array2)
console.log(areArraysEqual(array1, array2))
console.log(areArraysEqual(array2, array3))
```

This is oversimplification as if you want to compare dates based on date part only it won't work.

Comment: thanks but date value can be change  it is not a fixed values [@józef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304474/j%c3%b3zef-podlecki)

Comment: It still should work. I provided sample data just for the snippet to work.

Comment: if dates value are change according to time. so this code will run properly? [@józef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304474/j%c3%b3zef-podlecki)

Comment: did you understand my problem? [@józef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304474/j%c3%b3zef-podlecki)

Comment: No, if time part changes and and date part stays the same the arrays won't be equal anymore. Updated answer. If you want to compare dates only by date part you have to strip time value from arrays

Comment: what should i do? if dates value are change [@józef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304474/j%c3%b3zef-podlecki)

Comment: `currentdate = new Date();` // 2020-05-07 14:15:00
`prevdate = new Date();`     // 2020-05-07 09:51:04 [@józef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304474/j%c3%b3zef-podlecki)